# Admin Info Mail on registration isn't send anymore

Tags: emails, joomla-3.9

I have setup a Joomla website with registration confirmation through admin.

- Global setting for mail sending - set to yes
- The user is set to get system mails
- Info mail to admin on registration - set to yes

It worked properly for weeks. I didn't change the settings. I have done only updates. I noticed now because people asked me, why they are not yet confirmed.

I did some tests:

- the registrant gets the first mail
- eventBooking does send mails
- the testmail worked

I don't have any idea what I could check additionally.

Installed extensions:

- EventBooking
- AdminTools
- JEvents
- Kunena
- AcyMailing 6

All mail sending happens via PHP/sendmail.

Comment: This question can be closed. Today I got again the admin mail without any changes to any settings. All tests where negative I made and now it works again. Don't ask me what happens wrong. Don't know how to close this correctly without an answer @mickmackusa

Comment: The moderators can assist with their super powers. I have called to them for you (don't remove your comment) A shame, really, because Pe7er clearly put some effort in.  Oh well, it happens from time to time that questions with extensive answers get deleted.  (Certainly happened to me multiple times.)

Comment: Although this is not a completely clear question with not enough information, (wans't marked as too broad or unclear though) and the described issue is not reproduceable anymore, and even if there was no issue at all on your end, I think we can keep this question as is, because there is a rather adequate answer with info and questions that could help someone in the future to troubleshoot a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

What **email sending method** do you use (see System > Global Conguration > Server > mail settings)? What email sending methods do your extensions use? (e.g. in Acymailing you can configure another mail server)

Do you send email with **PHP/Sendmail** directly from your webserver,
or use SMTP and send all mail via an **external SMTP** server?

Maybe the mail is sent correctly, but **refused at some of the receiving mail servers** because they consider it as spam.

Could you **check the mail headers** in the mail notification that you received?
Do you see anything in the mail header regarding spam or warnings?

Could you check the **SPF** (Sender Policy Framework) records of your domain name (in your DNS server? Is your webserver or the external SMTP server allowed to send mail on your behalf?

Did you configure **DKIM or DMARC** (also in the DNS of your domain name)?
Could you test if you have configured SPF. DKIM, DMARC correctly?

There are some online test tools available to test your SPF. DKIM, DMARC settings:

- https://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx
- https://mxtoolbox.com/dkim.aspx
- https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/dkim/dkim-check/

**Edit**: Also check the "**IP Reputation**" of the server that sends the mail (your webserver or the SMTP server). Some receiving mail servers use blacklists to check the incoming mail for spam.

Some online tools to **check the IP reputation**:

- https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx
- https://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check
- https://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php

Comment: Sorry forgot the send method. All uses PHP/sendmail. The other stuff I need to check

Comment: Please do not post questions that seek clarification in your "answer". When you need additional details or diagnostics to be executed by the OP so that you can deliver a precise solution, please post them as comments under the question.  If a question has not provided adequate details, then the question is currently "Too Broad" and is not yet ready to receive answers.  Your (very careful and comprehensive) support is welcome but it is fashioned more for a forum / thread style format.  Please keep content in the designed sections.

Comment: All question details belong in the question body (not in comments under the question or under answers). All answers should provide a clear and educational resolution for the question asked.  Comments should be used to seek clarifications and advise about diagnostics and associated advice that does not solve the question.  Comments should be considered temporary as they can be erased by other volunteers, permanently, and without a trace.  @pe7er I love how much effort you have put into your post, I just want to guide you regarding where certain pieces of support should be posted.  Great work.